# How to keep search working on modified render columns DataTables.js

Tags: datatables

How to keep search working on modified render columns DataTables.js ?

please check below snippet, try to search `a test3` / `a test4` it will resulting `No matching records found`.

```js
const someData = [
  { id: 1, keyword: "keyword a", value: ["a test1", "a test2", "a test3", "a test4"]}
];

$(document).ready( function () {
  $('#table').DataTable({
    data: someData,
    columns: [
      { 
        data: "keyword",
        render: function( data, type, row, meta ) {
          var value = `<a href="my_keyword?id=${row.id}">${row.keyword}</a>`;
          return value;
        }
      },
      { 
        data: "value",
        render: function( data, type, row, meta ) {
          var value = "";
          if ( data.length > 2 ) {
            data.forEach( function(v, i) {
              if ( i < 2 ) value += `${v}<br/>`;
              else if ( i == 2 ) value += `. . . . .`
            });
          } else {
            for (var i=0; i<3; i++ ) {
              value += data[i] ? `${data[i]}<br/>`: `<br/>`
            }
          }
          return value;
        }
      }
    ]
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Keyword</th>
      <th>Value</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for now i'm using this hacky way to make it work, i'm add row with original value and set it `visible: false` on `columnDefs`, if there a right way to do it i'll accept it as an answer.

```js
const someData = [
  { id: 1, keyword: "keyword a", value: ["a test1", "a test2", "a test3", "a test4"]}
];

$(document).ready( function () {
  $('#table').DataTable({
    data: someData,
    columns: [
      { 
        data: "keyword",
        render: function( data, type, row, meta ) {
          var value = `<a href="my_keyword?id=${row.id}">${row.keyword}</a>`;
          return value;
        }
      },
      { 
        data: "value",
        render: function( data, type, row, meta ) {
          var value = "";
          if ( data.length > 2 ) {
            data.forEach( function(v, i) {
              if ( i < 2 ) value += `${v}<br/>`;
              else if ( i == 2 ) value += `. . . . .`
            });
          } else {
            for (var i=0; i<3; i++ ) {
              value += data[i] ? `${data[i]}<br/>`: `<br/>`
            }
          }
          return value;
        }
      },
      {
        data: "value"
      }
    ],
    columnDefs: [
      {
        targets: 2,
        visible: false
      }
    ]
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Keyword</th>
      <th>Value</th>
      <th>Value</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```